# Zend Framework 1.8 Autoloading Zend_Gdata_YouTube VideoQuery.php

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm having issues with Zend_Gdata_YouTube.

It seems unable to locate the file VideoQuery.php despite the fact it is one of the directories mentioned in the warning messages.

Also I created a standalone version of the example just including 'Zend/Gdata/YouTube.php'. This works fine.

I've dropped the error messages then the class followed by the working example into a paste bin.

[Paste Bin](http://pastebin.com/f745b7923)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error after I upgraded from ZF 1.8.0 to 1.8.4, after searching for a solution with no luck I posted my error on the ZF Gdata mail list and Trevor Johns was nice enough to get back to me with this response:

"This looks like this issue:

```
http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-7013
```

This will be fixed in the next release of Zend Framework. If you don't
want to wait that long, you can either:

1. Download a development snapshot from here:

hxxp://framework.zend.com/code/browse/~tarball=zip/Zend_Framework/standard/trunk/trunk.zip

2. Use version 1.8.3:

hxxp://framework.zend.com/releases/ZendFramework-1.8.3/ZendFramework-1.8.3.tar.gz

3. Don't use Zend_Loader's autoloader functionality. (This bug only
   seems to show up if you're trying to autoload the classes.)"

I'll be rolling back my ZF version until the next release.

p.s. had to substitute http with hxxp because "new users can only post a maximum of one hyperlink" apparently.

Answer (score 0):

The files Zend\Gdata\Media\Extension\VideoQuery.php and Zend\Gdata\YouTube\Extension\VideoQuery.php do not exist in the framework. I think the file you want is Zend\Gdata\YouTube\VideoQuery.php

Does this help? What code is using these classes, your code or the framework code?

Comment: The error occurs when I call the line bellow.

$query = $this->youtubeInterface->newVideoQuery();

I assumed the erronious call is being made by the framework class becuase youtubeInterface is an instance of Zend_Gdata_YouTube.